# POJO serialization problems

Tags: java, android, firebase

In the past I have had no problems serializing and deserializing POJOs using GSon library. But ever since I modularization my project and updated my Android studio to 4.1, any POJO I try to serialize returns me a bad value here is an example.

The expected result

```
dSecBook.toString ==> DSecBook{sd='for the love of God and I  not e', np='26.5', op='null', img='null', id='null'}
```

the result I'm getting

```
dSecBook.toJSon ==> {"b":"for the love of God and I not e","c":"26.5"}
```

Here is my POJO which is an SQL query derivative

```
public class DSecBook implements Serializable {
    @ColumnInfo(name = "short_description")
    public String sd;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "newPrice")
    public String np;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "oldPrice")
    public String op;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "pro_download_thumbUrl")
    public String img;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "proID")
    public String id;

    public DSecBook() {
        //for firebase
    }

    public DSecBook(String sd, String np, String op, String img, String id) {
        this.sd = sd;
        this.np = np;
        this.op = op;
        this.img = img;
        this.id = id;
    }
    ........
}
```

Problem is even firebase is giving the same result, this is killing my work

Please help

Comment: Add  `@field:SerializedName("<your_variable_name>")` annotation on every variable.

Comment: thanks its worked.. but is there a reason why its not straight forward anymore especially for firebase database? the value pairs are loosing there names.. any thoughts?

Comment: You might be using Pro-Gaurd, which encrypts your code and potentially changed the variable name to some random alphabetical character sequence. So the serialization doesn't recognize that variable. So `field:SerializedName` annotation will define that whatever the variable name is, it should point to the variable which has the name defined in the annotation.

Comment: thank u so much.. that makes a lot of sense